# Edit arm thumb2 intelhex file

Tags: arm, patching, binary-editing

I have intelhex file to arm 32 bits thumb 2.

I want edit this file add/ change instructions.

Looking for easy and free tool (prefer gui windows tool ) to do it please.

Answer (score 1):

Convert from hex to bin, patch it, then convert it back. The main issue is that in HEX format there will be the base address, and you need to specify it when converting back.

Don't know any GUI tool, here's а console one: [Hex2bin](http://hex2bin.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind it being python instead, I think you could do something pretty easily by combining the bincopy library (for the conversions to/from) and Capstone/Keystone for disassembling the old and assembling the new instructions.